# Parsing in Clojure

Tags: clojure

1. I am aware of edn/read-string
2. In Haskell, I tend to use Parsec https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec
3. I need to parse an Algo/Pascal like programming language. What are the suggested libraries to use for parsing in Clojure?

EDIT: 4. Bonus if there's a way to do this via a core.logic like manner, where a "prioritized" conde would specify the options (and the order to resolve ambiguity).

Comment: Did you do any Google search for Clojure parser combinator libraries?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl: Yes, there's instaparse, parsatron, kern, and a number of blog posts -- with no clear winner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really look at [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse). It is one of the best front end parsing libraries I've ever used. It is a lively project with steady advancements.

Comment: I agree - I have had great luck with Instaparse.  Of the 2 formats available, I prefer ABNF.

Comment: In practice, the decision of "well, if it's ambigious, let's just get all possible derivations" seems a bit impractical (as it may cause exponential blowup)

Comment: @eavdb It will refine that as you clean up the rules in your grammar. It is very performant as of late.

Comment: @FrankC. (Correct me if I'm wrong -- long time since I did compilers). Ambiguities in CFGs can be *detected* based on looking at the grammar alone [without any input]. If that's the case, naively, it seems like a library should detect the ambiguities and inform the human to fix it -- rather than wait until run time and generate all possible parses. I'm sure that instaparse has it's own valid reasons for the design decisions it made, I'm just not sure it works well with my goals.

Comment: @eavdb - Instaparse only provides the full universe of possibilities if you request it, otherwise you get one solution. My suggestion would be to try it out with a reasonably representative grammar and data feed. I had to spend more time with something like Owl derivatives versus something less expressive and loose.